# How to extract contents from this .DIG file?

Tags: file-format

I have this .DIG file from a PS2 game:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8-7FMP3lW8cU3NqUmNUcWdhcEk

Apparently, it should contain most of the game data, except cutscene movies and voiceovers, which are stored in different files. I could identify and extract audio with the IECS header from it. But how do I extract the rest? I'm particularly interested in textures, and above all, the dialogue files.

Answer (score 2):

See my answer to [this question](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/15893/20928). There, I note two primary forums dedicated to reversing file formats: [XeNTaX](http://forum.xentax.com/) and [ZenHAX](http://zenhax.com/index.php). If there aren't already .DIG scripts therein, you can sign up and inquire in the appropriate forum on each site, respectively. You can also try Googling for something like *[QuickBMS .DIG PS2](https://www.google.com/search?q=QuickBMS%20.DIG%20PS2&rlz=1C1CHZL_enUS745US745&oq=QuickBMS%20.DIG%20PS2&aqs=chrome..69i57.8695j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)* or *[MultiEx .DIG PS2](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHZL_enUS745US745&q=MultiEx%20.DIG%20PS2&oq=MultiEx%20.DIG%20PS2&gs_l=psy-ab.3...22710.23742.0.23885.7.7.0.0.0.0.60.364.7.7.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0.87a4wTARdMw)* (QuickBMS and MultiEx are scripting tools supported via the ZenHAX and XeNTaX forums). In doing so myself, [here](http://zenhax.com/viewtopic.php?t=2675) and [here](https://forum.xentax.com/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=10998) are results you may find of interest.

Comment: Thank you. I checked that script. Unfortunately, most of the extracted content consists of .raw files with an unknown compression algorithm, so I don't know how to proceed from there. The .raw files begin with 00 05. For example, this small one:

Comment: 00 05 40 0C 08 10 00 04 80 03 02 4C 04 D8 E2 C8 
91 01 A0 01 06 60 0A 30 00 7C 80 01 08 02 3C 72 
E4 C8 91 23 47 8E 1C 39 72 E4 88 80 80 01 8E 10 
D0 77 49 20 C0 00 14 01 16 40 0A B0 40 86 11 8B 
44 40 08 08 A0 20 40 10 01 17 18 04 18 21 C2 88 
FF FF 0F 02 5C F3 1F 00 43 80 FB 7E 1D 38 70 E0 
40 00

Ring any bells? The only files that can be identified are the audio ones, with the IECS header. The rest is like this.

Comment: I recommend registering and inquiring on one (or both) of those two forums--in those related threads I linked, perhaps. Both communities are usually pretty good about responding and are far more in-tune with the minutiae of reversing file formats than I am.