# Tomb Raider I Add Subtitle

Tags: tools

I want to translate Tomb Raider 1 into my language. I am able to change texts in the menu but I also want to add subtitles to cutscenes. Is it possible to add subtitles to cutscene.phd files?

Someone actually managed to add texts to cutscenes in 4th game with reverse engineering, even though it didn't support subtitles. There is currently a language patch for Last Revelation right now. And I can't reach the ones who made it however as I much do want to ask them how they even did that.

Answer (score 2):

Before trying to dive into reversing that file, start by taking a look around [Tomb Raider Forums](http://www.tombraiderforums.com/forumdisplay.php?s=6f1b1b135e1d97614dac637a326c5386&f=6) and perhaps inquire there. Without us having much to go on, the most we can give you is generic information. If need be, take a look at [this answer regarding help reversing file formats](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/15892/how-to-decrypt-encrypted-script-files-for-a-game/15893#15893). There are many communities out there well-suited to help you deal with that game (and perhaps that file specifically).

Comment: Though I checked up on Tomb Raider Forums, I couldn't find an answer about this issue. I also made a topic about this but unfortunately they don't know either. What ways should I follow to add this with Reverse Engineer? Is there any guide for this? And with which program I can put it through?

Comment: Unless someone has developed a custom tool for that file type, it's not going to be as simple as feeding it through a particular program, unfortunately. The other forums I link to in the other reply I noted, XeNTaX and ZenHAX, are the two communities out there that deal specifically in reversing file formats, so sign up there and inquire. If they can't help you, then I'd recommend a different approach, like perhaps a DLL injection where you hook a function related to the messages that appear on the screen. That also isn't a trivial matter for beginners, unfortunately, but you can research.